# Can't uninstall Android Studio on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, mobile-development

I want to Uninstall Android Studio, but it's not showing in the control panel programs and features, and I can't find the uninstaller. Does anyone know how to uninstall it?

or reinstalling it for the matter?

Comment: For whomever is voting to close this as general computing, please [read the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) carefully: "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic.  Questions about using software are only off-topic if they do not "directly involve tools used primarily for programming."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running into the same issue, tried removing the folder and reinstalling Android Studio but same result. The entry was available in the "programs and features" but when I tried uninstalling I'd get something along "program already uninstalled, remove from list?" which was an error.

What fixed it for me was running geek uninstaller, it showed up there and when I double-clicked it it started the uninstall process normally.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. This is how I solved mine: I downloaded the zip file of an older Android Studio version from here (https://developer.android.com/studio/archive). For me, I picked Android Studio 4.1 Canary 2 released on Mar 9, 2019. I am guessing you can pick most of the older ones and it will have the uninstall.exe program in it. Without decompressing the zip file, I just opened the zip file found the uninstall.exe program at the bottom of list right away. I copied the uninstall.exe and pasted it on my current Android Studio file folder. Double clicked it, and Windows uninstalled the program completely. I made sure to check the box where you want to remove the Android User settings as well (up to you what you prefer).

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you have never installed it. You may have just downloaded the zip and clicked .exe

In that case you can easily download another/newer version and do the same.

It's also possible to have multiple versions on your drive and run them separately. (That's recommended if you use alpha channels, so you can switch to a stable channel if something is not working correctly)

Comment: I downloaded the exe from the official site and ran that. It installed AS Arctic Fox but did not create the uninstall.exe file. Seems like a bug/omission in the installer.

Comment: I am running into this as well.  the `uninstall.exe` is missing from the root Android Studio folder

Comment: Yes, I have discovered the same issue, and I have only one version installed.

Comment: Yes, I am discovering the same issue today.  I installed Android Studio on to Windows 10, and cannot remove it.  I removed it via Control Panel, but it remains in my system.  When I try to install from the installer file, it only allows me to install into a new, empty folder.  This sucks.  I hate computer programs and files that remain as clutter on my computer.  How can this be fixed?

Comment: Am glad that I installed Android Studio 4 years ago and never uninstalled it. I only update the software :)   And I can uninstall it anytime I want  :)  I currently have Artic Fox now :)